# Error when installing XP after win 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-error-reporting

My machine was running win 7. For some reason I had to install XP. So inputted the XP CD on the machine and started to installation. While installing, the process formated the C:\ drive and then copied the XP files into C:\ drive. then restarted. After restarting I saw a message saying: *Error loading operating system*.
How to solve this issue to be able to install XP please?

Comment: I think I know that is wrong. How menu partitions do you have? If you have a second one, could be that the windows 7 wrote the boot sectors to the second partitions and is trying to start from there, but you don't have windows 7 on C any more.

Comment: I had only one HDD attached when installing XP.

Comment: And there is only one partition?

Comment: No. 5 partitions.

Comment: If you have 5 paritions on a single disk that indicates GPT. Please confirm, if you are, then Windows XP cannot be installed on that disk.

Comment: I have faced this problem - but in a different setup. I had programs that would run only in Win 98 but I had Win XP installed in my PC. When i try to install Win 98 it simply would not get installed. My understanding is a newer version of an MS operating system will not allow an old version of the MS OS to be installed.

Comment: No it's not correct. Because when you put the 98, the system boots from it and doesn't go to the XP's environment (in your case) to let the 98 be installed or not. The problem has to do with some small thing else!